$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1, 1\leq p\leq \infty$, a multiplier is bounded on $L^{p}$ if it is bounded on $L^{q}$

On wikipedia, it was mentioned that for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1, 1\leq p\leq \infty$, a multiplier is bounded on $L^{p}$ if it is bounded on $L^{q}$. I wonder what proof of this would be.

For any $f \in L^{2} \cap L^{p}$, a multiplier $T$ is defined by $\widehat{Tf}(\xi) = m(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$, where $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $m$ is a measurable function. And it said to bounded for $p\in [1,\infty]$ if $\|Tf\|_{p}\leq C_{p}\|f\|_{p}$ for $f \in L^{p} \cap L^{2}$
I felt to prove this, we would treat $Tf$ as a distribution, and deduce that $\langle Tf,g \rangle = \langle f, T^{*}g \rangle$, and then it is sufficient to show that $T^{*}$ is bounded for $p$ iff $T$ is bounded for $p$. However, I'm having difficulty showing this step. I felt that $\widehat{T^{*}f}(\xi) = m(-\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$, but this might be wrong.

Hi, it seems to be Holder Inequality.
